# Who maintain the session - Is it application framework or application server?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I am curious, for example, when I use spring framework on tomcat server , who actually maintain the session. In other word, does spring itself have their own mechanism/logic to maintain the session, or does it delegate the session maintenance to the tomcat server?

Comment: Session is maintained by servlet container, i.e by Catalina in case of Tomcat. So basically, you can say it is maintained by Tomcat. Spring MVC is using servlets internally , so to maintain session following mechanism could be used : URL rewriting, Session ID or hidden fields.